# Problem with Hough lines in OpenCV, how to go from a large number of Hough lines to one line per red duct tape instead of something like this

Tags: python, opencv, hough-transform, houghlines

I have this code now and it is great for detecting the red lines in my video, the issue is that I'm currently getting around 40 lines for one red line (see photo), and I'd like to reduce this to just 1 so that I can easily determine the intersections and subsequently the corner points of my red squares, anyone has an idea?:

Code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


def detect_grid(frame):
   
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

 
    lower_red = np.array([0, 100, 100])
    upper_red = np.array([10, 255, 255])

    mask1 = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red)


    lower_red = np.array([140, 20, 20])
    upper_red = np.array([180, 255, 255])

  
    mask2 = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red)

  
    red_mask = mask1 + mask2

 
    kernel = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8)
    red_mask = cv2.morphologyEx(red_mask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
    red_mask = cv2.morphologyEx(red_mask, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

    lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(red_mask, 1, np.pi / 180, threshold=50, minLineLength=50, maxLineGap=5)

    if lines is not None:
        for line in lines:
            x1, y1, x2, y2 = line[0]
            cv2.line(frame, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), 5)


cap = cv2.VideoCapture('redline_rectified.mp4')

while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        break

  
    detect_grid(frame)

  
    cv2.imshow('Grid Detection', frame)

   
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord(' '):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

What i get now:

[image: what i get now]

original:

[image: original]

Comment: Your red lines are too thick.  Try to skeletonize (thin) them. See skimage.morphology.skeletonize at https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/edges/plot_skeleton.html

Comment: Do you want one square only?

Comment: I have the problem that I need to precisely locate my drone in coordinates based on this grid (from which I receive these images). I initially thought about doing this by calculating the intersections of my Hough lines to obtain the corners of my squares. Then, I would find the center of each square and determine which center is closest to the center of my frame. Do you think this is a good approach?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, I solve line detection problems via on contour detection and analyzing contour basically manually. Since your inputs are clear I continued by modifying your code.

Here are the steps I applied for your case: if 2 lines are close to each other than ignore one of those. I got this output at the end which has clear lines.

[image]

Here is the code. Beginning part is same just modifiedthe end of function:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


def detect_grid(frame):
   
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    lower_red = np.array([0, 100, 100])
    upper_red = np.array([10, 255, 255])

    mask1 = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red)

    lower_red = np.array([140, 20, 20])
    upper_red = np.array([180, 255, 255])

    mask2 = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red)

    red_mask = mask1 + mask2

    kernel = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8)
    red_mask = cv2.morphologyEx(red_mask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
    red_mask = cv2.morphologyEx(red_mask, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

    lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(red_mask, 1, np.pi / 180, threshold=350, minLineLength=50, maxLineGap=50)

    if lines is not None:
        # Filter out lines that are too close
        filtered_lines = []
        for line in lines:
            x1, y1, x2, y2 = line[0]
            p1 = np.array([x1, y1])
            p2 = np.array([x2, y2])
            too_close = False

            for other_line in filtered_lines:
                x3, y3, x4, y4 = other_line
                p3 = np.array([x3, y3])
                p4 = np.array([x4, y4])

                # Calculate Euclidean distance
                distance = np.linalg.norm(np.cross(p2 - p1, p1 - p3)) / np.linalg.norm(p2 - p1)

                if distance < 10:
                    too_close = True
                    break

            if not too_close:
                filtered_lines.append(line[0])

        for line in filtered_lines:
            x1, y1, x2, y2 = line
            cv2.line(frame, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 255), 3)

    cv2.imwrite("/home/ubuntu/a.jpg", frame)

img = cv2.imread("/home/ubuntu/lines.png")
detect_grid(img)
```

Comment: Great, thank you! Now, I have the problem that I need to precisely locate my drone in coordinates based on this grid (from which I receive these images). I initially thought about doing this by calculating the intersections of my Hough lines to obtain the corners of my squares. Then, I would find the center of each square and determine which center is closest to the center of my frame. Do you think this is a good approach?

Comment: I amnot sure the best one but the first one to come to my mind also. why not. if it works go on that way

Comment: I've been able to determine all the corner points by now. How could I do it better? The goal is to receive a live feed from a drone flying above a grid, and I need to accurately display the drone's location based on the coordinates of the red squares (for example, the starting square is (0,0), and the one above it is (0,1), etc.). To determine which square I am in, I can use the approach outlined above. However, within the same square, I also need to know my precise location (e.g., whether I'm at the top or the bottom). Do you have any ideas on how to best approach this?